# How to keep the number of decimal points consistent in the coefficients of formulas in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, decimal

I tried to lable two formulas on the figure ploted by ggplot. However, the number of decimal places in one formula does not match the number of decimal places of the other formula.

Here is the original data:

```
df<-structure(list(Treatment = c("Irrigated", "Irrigated", "Irrigated", 
"Irrigated", "Irrigated", "Irrigated", "Irrigated", "Irrigated", 
"Irrigated", "Irrigated", "Irrigated", "Irrigated"), Year = c(2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021
), Variety = c("Sultana - MG 000", "ES Pallador - MG I", "Isidor - MG I", 
"Santana - MG I/II", "Blancas - MG II", "Ecudor - MG II", "Sultana - MG 000", 
"ES Pallador - MG I", "Isidor - MG I", "Santana - MG I/II", "Blancas - MG II", 
"Ecudor - MG II"), FTSWt = c(0.91, 0.79, 0.92, 0.48, 0.51, 0.46, 
0.93, 0.59, 0.58, 0.44, 0.48, 0.52), SLA = c(85.38, 111.94, 108.56, 
120.54, 130.14, 123.25, 109.05, 149.97, 168.64, 162.96, 140.18, 
175.1)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Here is the code I used:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)
library(stats)
library(ggpmisc)
ggplot(df, aes(x = FTSWt, y = SLA, group = Year)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = as.factor(Year), shape = as.factor(Year)), size =3) +
  geom_smooth(
    method = "lm",
    formula = y ~ x,
    se = FALSE,
    aes(color = as.factor(Year))
  ) +
  stat_poly_eq(
    aes(label = paste(
      gsub('\\.', "*paste('.')*",
           after_stat(eq.label)),
      gsub('\\.', ".", after_stat(rr.label)),
      sep = "*plain(\";\")~~"
    )),
    coef.digits = 4,
    label.x.npc = 0.85,
    label.y.npc = c(0.9, 0.85),
    formula = y ~ x,
    parse = TRUE,
    size = 4.5,
    color = c("black", "red")
  ) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = Variety, color = as.factor(Year)), size = 4.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red", "black", "red")) +
  labs(y = expression(paste('SLA (cm' ^ 2, '·', 'g' ^ -1, ')')),
       x = "FTSWt") +
  theme_bw()
```

Here is the figure I got

[image]

How can I change the number 59.23 in the blue circle to one decimal place 59.2 without changing the other values?

Answer (score 1):

We can manipulate the formula labels just as any
other character string. In the example below I use `stringr::str_replace_all()`
to find all decimals with 2 digits and replace it with the first digit. I
removed the parts of the plot that are not essential for the forumla labels.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)
library(ggrepel)
library(stringr)

ggplot(df, aes(x = FTSWt, y = SLA, group = Year)) +
  stat_poly_eq(
    aes(label = paste(
      gsub('\\.', "*paste('.')*",
           after_stat(eq.label) |> str_replace_all("\\.([0-9])[0-9]", "\\.\\1")),
      gsub('\\.', ".", after_stat(rr.label)),
      sep = "*plain(\";\")~~"
    )),
    coef.digits = 4,
    coef.keep.zeros = FALSE,
    label.x.npc = 0.85,
    label.y.npc = c(0.9, 0.85),
    formula = y ~ x,
    parse = TRUE,
    size = 4.5,
    color = c("black", "red")
  ) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = "", color = as.factor(Year)), size = 4.5)
```

[image]